# Can't add comment with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to add comment using ajax.
Here is my ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_comment").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var article_id = {{article.id}};
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/addcomment/" + article_id + '/',
            type: "get",
            success: function(result){

                        if(result === "validation error"){
                            alert(result);
                        }else{
                            var data = JSON.parse(result);
                            $("#comment_block").append("<div class = "comment"><span>" + data['owner'] + "</span><p>" + data['comment_text'] + "</p></div>");
                        }
                    }
            });
    });

});
```

Here is my form of adding comment in django template:

```
</div>
    {% if username %}
    <form action="/articles/addcomment/{{ article.id }}/" method="post" id = "comment_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" class="button"  value="Добавить комментарий" id = "add_comment">
    </form>
    {% endif %}

 </div>
```

Trying to debug, I noticed that it doesn't even step into ajax body. What am I doing wrong then? 
I've done ajax query with counting likes and had success in that.

Comment: you have a syntax error in `var article_id = {{article.id}}` what are you trying to do here... just try `var article_id = article.id;`

Comment: and you have form action, by default it will trigger  form action not AJAX call

Comment: no, it's not syntax error. It's django template tag.

Comment: kartheek, what shoud I do then?

Comment: {{article.id}} and you have this too. what article.id is?

Comment: I pass article object to template. Then {{article.id}} returns id of that article, when I'm now at.

Answer (score 1):

Change to the following:

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#comment_form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var article_id = $(this).find('.article_id').value();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/addcomment/" + article_id + '/',
        type: "post",
        success: function(result){

                    if(result === "validation error"){
                        alert(result);
                    }else{
                        var data = JSON.parse(result);
                        $("#comment_block").append("<div class = 'comment'><span>" + data['owner'] + "</span><p>" + data['comment_text'] + "</p></div>");
                    }
                }
        });
    return false;
});
```

});

Django Template:

```
</div>
{% if username %}
<form action="/articles/addcomment/{{ article.id }}/" method="post" id = "comment_form">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="hidden" class="article_id" value="{{ article.id }}" />
<input type="submit" class="button"  value="Добавить комментарий" id = "add_comment">
</form>
{% endif %}

 </div>
```

Comment: When debugging, I noticed that program doesn't walk into ajax body.

Comment: Try replacing the django code of '{{article.id}}' with a static number, such a '2' and see if it runs the ajax body.

Comment: I'll give you the best way to proceed with this. Modifying my answer atm.

Comment: Basically, switched from `click` to `submit` event for the form.  Also, your ajax was doing a `GET`, while your form was doing a `POST` on the same URL. Which is which?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

## **HTML**

```
</div>
    {% if username %}
    <form action="#" method="post" id = "comment_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="text" name = "article" value="{{ article.id }}" id = "article_id">
    <input type="text" name = "comment" value="comment goes here" id = "comment_text">
    <input type="submit" class="button"  value="???????? ???????????" id = "add_comment">
    </form>
    {% endif %}

 </div>
```

## jQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_comment").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var article_id = $('#article_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/addcomment/" + article_id + '/',
            type: "POST", /*i belive you are posting data to BE api*/
            data:{'comment':"your comment goes here"}, /* use this get what given in input  $("#comment_text").val()*/
            success: function(result){
                        /*process data after success call*/
                    }
            });
    });

});
```